# Qt raw vs std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, shared-ptr

I noticed that when substituting raw pointers with shared_ptr in QT, my code does not work anymore.
For example, if instead of

```
 QTreeWidgetItem* vItem(new QTreeWidgetItem(ItemTitle));
```

I use

```
 std::shared_ptr<QTreeWidgetItem> vItem(new QTreeWidgetItem(ItemTitle));
```

then, either the program crashes or nothing is done (even if I use the .get() function to get the
raw pointer from the shared one later in my code). Does anybody knows what could be the cause?

Comment: Why do you use a smart pointer with a Qt model item in the first place? You probably should not do that.

Comment: I was not sure that the raw pointer will cause memory leak...

Comment: That is always a valid worry, but the solution is not to add random "fix", but instead to understand the life-cycle and ownership status of the object. But yeah, that is not always easy to know what's the right thing, especially in C++ when using some framework...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using shared pointer with Qt model items causes an ownership conflict: `QTreeWidget` takes ownership of any `QTreeWidgetItem` you pass to it. `std::shared_ptr` also owns its item. Both assume they can delete the item themselves and that nobody else will delete it behind their back.

In such situations, where Qt takes ownership of the pointers (other example: parent `QObject` taking ownership of its children), one cannot use `std::shared_ptr`/`QSharedPointer` at the same time. `std::shared_ptr` only works well when using `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` exclusively to hold pointers to that particular object.