# stl smart pointers and qt objects

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, smart-pointers

Sorry for my English. Executes a test job, and I was told in the feedback: "you can not just transfer the right of ownership of objects Qt smart pointers stl".
Here is an example of the job code:

```
std::shared_ptr<QWidget> window = std::make_shared<QWidget>();
```

And:

```
std::shared_ptr<AdaptedWidget> WindowManager::findWindow(std::string title)
{
    auto windowsStack = m_windowsStack;

    while(!windowsStack.empty())
    {
        auto window = windowsStack.top();
        windowsStack.pop();

        if(title == window->windowTitle().toStdString())
        {
            return window;
        }
    }
    return std::shared_ptr<AdaptedWidget>();
}
```

As used in this case, the objects Qt in conjunction with smart pointers STL?

Comment: Have you heard of the phrase *"When in Rome, do as the Romans do"*? ... `QObject`s and all its derivatives have an [ownership](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876835/qt-raw-vs-stdshared-ptr?rq=1) model that doesn't fit too well with the semantics `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: The feedback is correct, but it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: @nax, please clarify what it is that you're asking (otherwise people might close your question).